# gets() and puts() showing characters that i did not enter

Tags: c, string, gets, puts

So I got the task to make program that will take input until I write `"KRAJ"`. But when I print it with `puts()` it will have 3 chars more in first 3 places. Let's say I write `"finish meKRAJ"` it would have to print only `"finish me"` but it prints `"ć[]'finish me"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char text[100];
    char entry[100];
    int i;
    int flag=1;
    int flag2;
    do{
        printf("Enter txt:finish by writing KRAJ\n");
        gets(entry);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(entry);i++){
            if(entry[i] == 'K' && entry[i+1] == 'R' && entry[i+2] == 'A' && entry[i+3] == 'J'){
                strncat(text,entry,i);
                flag=0;
                flag2=1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                flag2=0;
            }
        }
    if(!flag2)strcat(text,entry);
    }while(flag);

    printf("\n You have entered:\n");
    puts(text);
    //testing first char

    printf("\nTesting first char:%c",text[0]);
    printf("\ntxt lenght:%d",strlen(text));


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed in C11.

Comment: `printf("\ntxt lenght:%d",strlen(text));` will invoke *undefined behavior* for passing data having wrong type: `%d` calls for `int`, but what is returned from `strlen` is `size_t`.

Comment: You are using variable having automatic storage duration `text` without initializing and invoking *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks,i used int lenVar = strlen(entry) and used it it for loop(i=0;i<lenVar;i++) and it is working

Comment: `int i;` should be `size_t i;` and `printf("\ntxt lenght:%d",strlen(text));` sdhould be `printf("\ntxt lenght:%zu",strlen(text));`

Comment: `gets` is not standard C! **Never ever** use it! Use `fgets` instead. (Modern implementations of the standard library should warn about code using it)

Comment: By the way Your program has a big problem if the Input is bigger then 99

Comment: 'length' is 'length' and not 'lenght'

Comment: replace `if(entry[i] == 'K' && entry[i+1] == 'R' && entry[i+2] == 'A' && entry[i+3] == 'J'){` with ==>>> `if( strcmp(entry, "KRAJ") == 0 ){`

Answer (score 3):

> Let's say I write "finish meKRAJ" it would have to print only "finish
>   me" but it prints "ć[]'finish me"

```
char text[100];
```

is never initialized, yet you call

```
strncat(text,entry,i);
```

and

```
if(!flag2)strcat(text,entry);
```

Those two calls will append your strings to whatever garbage is in `text[100]` when your program starts.

Comment: `is never initialized, yet you call` it doesn't need to be, this is a common error. The call of `strcpy` is missing before `strcat` Of course that this program has a lot of other problems

Comment: @Michi One [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) definition of "uninitialized" is  *not  declared  with  an  initializer  and  no  assignment  to  it  has  been
performed prior to use*.  Calling `strcpy()` would be an assignment. Note also that [`strcat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcat.html) requires that  both arguments be `NUL`-terminated strings.

Comment: Agree, but what's happens if the input will be only 15 and you initialize the whole array with ZERO's?

Comment: `Note also that strcat() requires that both arguments be NUL-terminated strings` Here is the part which you didn't understand when I said that the call of `strcpy` was missing.